# JPA or Hibernate Mapping multiple Objects from Database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an application with 2 entities USER , ROLE having ManytoMany relationship.
So in database I have 3 tables user, role, user_role.
I am using Spring Boot for Application.
Now I m designing Admin Panel so I need to display all info of every user.

Now i got stuck how to fetch role with user.
I am using JPA + Hibernate

Comment: Please post your code that we can easily provide you solutions.

Answer (score 0):

it basically need 2 query.
1. are you admin?
2. find every user.

```
User user = UserRepository.findByUserId(your pk or id .. etc);
boolean isAdmin = "ADMIN".equals(user.getRole()) (if your field is String or Role.ADMIN ... etc)

if(isAdmin){
    List<User> everyUsers = UserRepository.findAll();
    return everyUsers;
}else{
    return "Not Auth";
}
```